# how come while loop skips char?

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to set a while loop to keep asking (y/n), but how come when I press 'y' and enter it skips "char itemtitle" and goes straight down to "double itemprice"? I'm really new to c++, please help, i'd apprreciate it

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

#define tax 9.99
#define shipping ("Free")

void printmessage ()
{
  cout << "*Thanks for your business! We'll ship out your item as soon as possible*\n"
              "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

   cout << "Write an invoice program and print it to the console.\n";
   cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n;

   cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n"
           "Welcome to my Pc Store.\n"
           "'Where Technology is served right'\n"
           "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n"<< endl;

   char name [256];
   cout << "Enter your full name: ";
   cin.getline (name, 256);

   char organization [256];
   cout << "What's your organization?: ";
   cin.getline (organization, 256);

   char quit = 'y';    
   do {
        char itemtitle [256];
        cout << "Enter name of Laptop you'd like to order: ";
        cin.getline (itemtitle, 256);

        double itemprice;
        cout << "Enter price of item: $";
        cin >> itemprice; 

        int quantity;
        quantity = 1;
        cout << "How many items?: ";
        cin >> quantity;

        if (quantity == 1) {     
            cout << "1 item(s)\n";  
        } else  {
           cout << quantity << " item(s)\n";
        } 

        cout << "Tax: $" << tax;

        double subtotal;
        subtotal = quantity * itemprice + tax;
        cout << "\nSub Total: $" << subtotal;

        cout << "\n";       
        cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n"
               "Validation:\n\n";

        cout << "Item(s):\t\t\t\t\t" << "Amount:\n";       
        cout << itemtitle << "\t\t\t\t\t$" << quantity * itemprice + tax; ;
        cout << "\n" << quantity << " * $" << itemprice << " + $" << tax;

        cout << "\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n\n";
        cout << "Payment (Credit/Debit only)!\n\n";

        double cardnum;
        cout << "Card Numbers: ";
        cin >> cardnum;

        int ssn;
        cout << "SSN: ";
        cin >> ssn;

        cout << "\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n"
               "Invoice Details:\n\n";

        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;
        time ( &rawtime );
        timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
        cout << "Date&Time: " << ("Current local time and date: %s", asctime (timeinfo));

        cout << name;
        cout << "\n" << organization;
        cout << "\n" << "("<< quantity << ")" << " " << itemtitle;

        cout << "\n\t\t\t" << "Total: $" << quantity * itemprice;
        cout << "\n\t\t\t" << "Tax: $" << tax;
        cout << "\n\t\t\t" << "Shipping: " << shipping;
        cout << "\n\n\t\t\t" << "Balance Due: $" << quantity * itemprice + tax;

        cout << "\n\t\t\t" << "Payment: " << "Paid" ;

        cout << "\n\n\nDo you want to continue shopping? (y/n): ";
        cin >> quit ;

        cout << "\n\n";

    } while (quit != 'n');

    cout << "\n\n\n";
    printmessage ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Same problem as always. cin leaves the \n in the buffer, so the next getline returns immediately.

Comment: Side-note: [too much `using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c) and too much `#define`.

Comment: Etienne please write a reply so I can do a formal upvote :)

Comment: @speeder I will not reply to a duplicate. I'm not a repwhore.

Comment: That's one god**** monolithic do-while loop you got there...

Answer (score 2):

`std::cin.operator>>()` leaves the `'\n'` character in the buffer, making it pretty much unusable with `getline`. You have to pick either and then change the code accordingly.

For example, use only `getline`, then parse the resulting string inside.

Comment: _Or_ you could use the `cin.ignore()` trick to empty the buffer after the `operator>>` call.

Comment: That's cryptic, though.

Comment: Well, we're talking about C++ here.

Answer (score 0):

When you use both "cin >>" and "cin.getline()" to read from user input, you will have this problem mostly. It seems that when using ">>" operator, after reading the input, '\n' is left in the input stream, which cause a following call to "getline" to return immediately.

Two solutions.

First, add "cin.ignore();" before "cin.getline(itemtitle, 256);". "cin.ignore()" extracts characters from the input sequence and discards them. It will clear the input stream.

Second, replace "cin.getline(itemtitle, 256);" with "cin >> itemtitle;". I suggest using either "cin.getline" or "cin >>" in your code, but don't use both. "cin >>" would be better.

Besides, should put "#include < ctime >" in the top of your code.